# Como capturar a Exception gerada por um método cujo o acesso não é autorizado por um determinado perfil de usuário

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, authorization

Como posso enviar ao usuário uma mensagem que a operação que ele deseja fazer não é autorizada?

Tenho na minha View um botão que chama uma função Javascript

```
 <button id="btninicio" onclick="salvaApontamento();">Inicio</button>
```

Essa função `salvaApontamento()` chama um método no meu Controller:

```
function salvaApontamento()
{
    startSpin();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: getBaseUrl() + "/Apontamentos/AlteraApontamento";,
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ apontamentos: jsonDataApontamentos }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            stopSpin();
            alert("Sucesso);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            stopSpin();
            alert("Erro: salvaApontamento() :(  " + data.message)           
        }
    });
}
```

Tenho um método no meu controller que faz alterações apenas se for o "Administrador" logado:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Authorize(Roles = "Administrador")]
 public JsonResult AlteraApontamento(ApontamentosOperacao apontamentos)
 {
    //faz o que eu preciso e retorna um Json...
 }
```

Debugando o código, percebi que se eu me logar como "Operador". Ao disparar a requisição, o retorno cai direto no error do Ajax e a minha requisição nem chega no método lá no Controller.

O "Administrador" e o "Operador" enxergam a mesma View. Eu gostaria de enviar uma mensagem para a View que informasse o usuário que o seu perfil não é válido. Que parâmetro eu preciso capturar na minha variável `data`, lá no javascript para saber que o método não pode ser acessado pelo usuário logado?

Seguindo a sugestão do amigo Eduardo, quando eu pego o statusCode no javascript do ajax, eu obtenho o código 200.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o usuário está autorizado, o meu objeto data retorna os dados que eu construí lá no método do Controller.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Creio que o que o Eduardo disse está correto.

Comment: Quando o usuário está autorizado, como é o objeto data retornado?

Comment: Eduardo, atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Quando o resultado retorna com erro, existe algum campo chamado `result`? Note que quando o resultado retorna OK, o valor de `result` é "success".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu lugar, eu faria meu próprio atributo de autorização com capacidade de devolver um erro 403 ou 405, dependendo do seu objetivo:

```
public class MeuAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) 
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(403);
        else
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    } 
}
```

O uso é idêntico:

```
[HttpPost]
[MeuAuthorize(Roles = "Administrador")]
public JsonResult AlteraApontamento(ApontamentosOperacao apontamentos)
{
   //faz o que eu preciso e retorna um Json...
}
```

E para a chamada do `Ajax`, [a resposta do @EduardoFernandes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74349/2999) atende bem.

Comment: Ótima ideia :)!!

Comment: Uma alternativa bem legal é utilizar HttpModule, que intercepta todas as requests e executa qualquer atividade customizada. Nesse ponto, pode-se tratar código não autorizado. Veja esse link com um tutorial legal de HttpModule e HttpHandler: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30907/The-Two-Interceptors-HttpModule-and-HttpHandlers

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez , a linha filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult(); sempre será executada, mesmo se a condição de cima for atendida. Existe algum motivo especial?

Comment: @EduardoFernandes `HttpHandler` é pra uma coisa mais abrangente. Como o caso do autor da pergunta é mais simples, derivar o atributo de autorização fica mais simples e elegante.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, a vantagem de se utilizar `HttpHandler` é que o gerenciamento desse código HTTP, e de qualquer outro, pode ser feito em apenas um local. Além disso, utilizando-se `HttpHandler`, todos os controllers terão comportamento igual para o tratamento desse problema e de qualquer outro que possa aparecer para autorização, sem a necessidade de se utilizar herança.

Comment: @EduardoFernandes Ainda assim, pro caso dele não tem necessidade disso. É só uma verificação simples de permissão.

Comment: @Emerson Tem razão. Alterei a resposta.

Comment: EduardoFernandes e @Cigano Morrison Mendes, implementei de acordo com as orientações que vocês me deram e deu certo. Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Coloque a tag de `statusCode` no seu javascript, como mostrado abaixo:

```
$.ajax({
  ....
  statusCode: {
    405: function() {
      alert( "Você não temn permisão para...." );
    }
  }
  ....
});
```

O Controlller retorna um erro de "Method Not Allowed", representado pelo código HTTP 405. Trate o mesmo com o código acima.

Comment: Eduardo, fiz o teste, mas o valor obtido no statusCode é 200.

Comment: Estranho.... como ele retorna um erro com status 200? O que mais vem no `data`?